# How can I select multiple values into locally declared variables in a SQL Server Stored Proc?

Tags: sql-server

Here's what I have:

```
DECLARE Name  VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE Pass  INT
SELECT  Name,
        Pass,
FROM    AdminTest
WHERE   TestId = @TestId
```

But this selects and reports.

How can I have the values stored into the local variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is incorrect declaration of variables. You should declare variables using `@`. Do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Name  VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Pass  INT
SELECT  @Name = Name,
        @Pass = Pass,
FROM    AdminTest
WHERE   TestId = @TestId
```